# Connecting to a Socket.IO server running in Node-Red on IBM Bluemix

Tags: socket.io, ibm-cloud, node-red

I've set up a Node-Red instance on IBM Cloud with a Socket.IO server using [node-red-contrib-socketio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-socketio).

I was able to subscribe to events on port 3000 on my local host fine but I'm having difficulty doing the same with the Node-Red instance on IBM Cloud.

1. According to my client console I seem to be able to connect but get no response using the following URL: `ws://MYAPP.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/red:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` Is this correct or should I be using something else like `ws://MYAPP.eu-gb.mybluemix.net:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` ?
2. Is any further configuration required in IBM Cloud to enable the connection?
3. If I need to authenticate within the URL I pass to the server is there a particular way that string should be structured?

Many thanks,

Comment: For reference the simplest solution was to use standard websockets as advised by @hardillb. Step 4 in the following developer recipe outlines the process: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/iot-temperature-and-moisture-sensor-integrated-to-node-red-and-bluemix-ibm/#r_step4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work on Bluemix.

The Bluemix router only forwards external traffic on ports 80 and 443 (http/https) to apps.

But the app may not be actually listening on those ports (The port to listen on is passed in to the application on start up in a environment variable).

You can not just pick an arbitrary ports and listen on.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb  Are there any documents you can point me to on configuring this in Bluemix. Otherwise would standard Websockets or MQTT be preferred for broadcasting my data externally in real time in the way I require.

Comment: You cannot configure this your app needs to listen on the port it's told to and only one thing can listen on that port. WebSockets works (this is how node-red does debug messages)